# How to add cellspacing and cellpadding in HTML tables generated by xtable?

Tags: r, xtable

I would like to add spacing or padding to a html table generated by xtable.
The print.xtable() parameter `html.table.attributes` doesn't work for me.
Here an example chunk that can be pasted in a Rmd document.

````
```{r results='asis'}
library(xtable)
print(xtable(cars), type='html',
      html.table.attributes = 'cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5"',
          include.rownames = FALSE, include.colnames=FALSE,
          comment = FALSE)
```
````

It's a simple standalone example and I wouldn't like to create a css file for this: [more details on the purpose](http://rpubs.com/paul4forest/132829).

Answer (score 3):

You can add CSS rules to a style sheet in the R Markdown document with the style tags.

```
 <style>
   th,td{
     padding:2px 5px 2px 5px;
   }
 </style>
```